# Subtract from a sequence of elements

Tags: r

New to R. Trying to subtract 5 from the 2nd, 4th, and 6th elements of the following:

```
x <- c(3, 12, 6, -5, 0, 8, 15, 1, -10, 7)

> x
 [1]   3  12   6  -5   0   8  15   1 -10   7
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depending on the exact output you are looking for try`x[c(2,4,6)] - 5` or `x[c(2,4,6)] <- x[c(2,4,6)] - 5` if you want to reassign the new values.

Comment: Thank you! This worked: x[c(2, 4, 6)] <- x[c(2, 4, 6)] -5

Answer (score 0):

```
x[seq(2,6,2)] = x[seq(2,6,2)] -5
```